# Auth0 subscription plan app_metadata

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, auth0, loopback

I'm developing a quiz app which requires authorization for only-subscribed members can see.

How to do that? I'm thinking of putting metadata (is_subscribed) to true for subscribed member and give the scope so he/she can gain permissions.

But, I don't know how to do it. Please help. The docs is so confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate concerns here.

- Where to keep the subscription information. `app_metadata` is fine, or you might choose to do so in a backend database (application specific). A client application will probably handle subscriptions and be in charge of updating that value. If you store the value in `app_metadata`, you will use [Management API v2](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/patch_users_by_id) to alter the user profile from the application that handles subscriptions.
- Add an authorization scope based on the subscription status. In this case, you would [use a rule to add a custom scope](https://auth0.com/docs/rules/current#api-authorization-modify-scope) based on the value of the `is_subscribed` field. I.e.:

```
function(user, context, callback) {
  if (user.app_metadata && user.app_metadata.is_subscribed) {
    context.accessToken.scope = ['read:quiz'];
  } else {
    // remove the ability to read a quiz if not subscribed.
    context.accessToken.scope = [];
  }
  callback(null, user, context);
}
```

If you decided to store the subscription information in a backend database instead of in the `app_metadata`, you would simply access the database from the rule in the above code.